# Iterate through a folder with the use of pathlib, I can´t open file with the use of path + value + string

Tags: python, for-loop, pathlib, unsupportedoperation

I would like to iterate through a folder with the help of **pathlib**.
The problem is, it seems, that I can´t combine a value with a string with the use of my path "**folder**".

The following error appears:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

This is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path

#import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
```

> if **name** == '**main**':

```
folder = Path('ASCII/')

TEST_NR = []

for ii in range(1,91):

    TEST_NR.append('Test' + str(ii))

DCT = {i:[] for i in TEST_NR}

for jj in TEST_NR:

    DCT['%s' % jj] = []

for kk in range(90):

    with open(folder / TEST_NR[kk] + '.txt') as f: ######### *ERROR* ##########

        for _ in range(17):

            next(f)

        for line in f:

            DCT[TEST_NR[kk]].append(line.strip().split(','))
```

I am sure its very basic but I don´t know how to handle it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the filename variable before passing it into `pathlib.Path`.
i.e.

```
for kk in range(90):
    var = TEST_NR[kk] + '.txt'
    with open(folder / var ) as f:
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another, more explicit<sup>1</sup> version would be:

```
for kk in range(90):
    file_path = folder / TEST_NR[kk]
    with open(file_path.with_extension('.txt')) as f:
```

Also, please pardon the unasked advice, but in Python we usually iterate directly through lists rather than using indices. In this case, your code would become:

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = Path('ASCII')

    # using a defaultdict will return an empty list when 
    # requesting an index that does not exist
    DCT = defaultdict(list)

    for test_num in range(1,91):
        test_path = Path(f'Test{test_num}')
        with open(folder / test_path.with_suffix('.txt')) as test_file:
            for _ in range(17):
                next(test_file)

            for line in test_file:
                DCT[test_path].append(line.strip().split(','))
```

### I

<sup>1 Explicit is better than implicit. ([The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))</sup>